# The emulator is unable to connect to the device

Tags: uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I'm getting the below error while running a UWP project in Windows 10 emulator using Visual Studio 2015.

[image: Error Message thrown by the emulator]

I have tried the below.
1. Hyper-V settings changes.
2. Running everything in administrator mode.

Still i found no solutions.

Comment: So you have checked [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd02b41d-02c6-4c57-8cf4-e405790ee4c8/uwpsdkproblem-with-windows-10-mobile-emulator?forum=wpdevelop)?

Comment: Yes. But no use. it doesn't works for me.

Comment: http://www.onteorasoftware.com/2016/12/fixing-your-hyper-v-emulators.html

Comment: For all the emulators you have the same issue? Please provide the emulator version and your uwp app version.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT
emulator version - 10.1.14393.0
UWP app version - you can take any UWP app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case the one who solved my problem was to run the XdeCleanup.exe, after run it my emulator began working again, of course this for windows 10.

it can be found here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\\XdeCleanup.exe

I ran it via command prompt as an administrator and it should:
deletes all emulator specific Hyper-V VMs, and it also deletes any VM checkpoints or saved states.

hopefully this solution works for you!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the solution which works for me is uninstalled the visual studio and then reinstall it resolves.

Comment: well if you happened to suffer this again you could try this, before thinking in reinstalling VS, its quicker than it.

Comment: This helped. THanks

Comment: You're welcome, dont forget to vote up for me answer.

Answer (score 4):

Do you see your "Virtual Switch" information under: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections? If not, you can try to recreate your "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" again from Hyper-V to see if that resolves your issue. Try these steps below:

1.) Open Hyper-V

2.) Shutdown any existing configured Phone emulators.

3.) Click on "Virtual Switch Manager"

4.) Click on the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"

5.) Remember what the settings are displayed there (because you will delete it and recreate it)

6.) Delete the existing "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking "Remove"

7.) Click "Apply" and "OK"

8.) Re-create the "Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch" by clicking the "New virtual network switch" and use the same settings you remembered in Step 5.

9.) Then try to F5 from Visual Studio - which should configure a new emulator on the right virtual switch.