# Hololens Emulator refuses to recognize keyboard or mouse input

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

The Hololens emulator version 10.0.19041.1140 takes forever to launch, and then gives the error message:

```
[XDE:014] The emulator is unable to connect to the device operating system:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to response Microsoft.Xde.Base.Connection.HyperVSocketEndpoint

Some functionality might be disabled.
```

Afterwards, neither keyboard nor mouse input is accepted. The HyperV setting described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-hololens-emulator) has been appropriately set on my device.

How can I get the emulator to launch, and when it does, how can I get it to accept keyboard and mouse input?

I have also tried running as an admin; no joy.

Comment: Have you tried this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133534/the-emulator-is-unable-to-connect-to-the-device. The poster got the same issue in the Windows10 emulator, and the solution that works for him is to reinstall the VS.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling VS is a multihour task which can break the rest of my universe, so this is a nonstarter for me.

Comment: We can understand your concern. To locate the issue we need to diagnose it deeper for you, and it will require you to provide more log information. In order to protect your privacy, it is recommended to open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport